# Access Control of parent page in iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a asp.net page (redaktionsplan.aspx), which contains a iframe, which also represent a asp.net-page:

```
<iframe src='test.aspx' height="1000px" width="700px" frameborder="0">
```

test.aspx contains a control (label1). Now, I want in the OnLoad-Event of the label1 (which is on test.aspx) (in CodeBehind of the label1) access a control which is on redaktionsplan.aspx.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access controls of another page on the server.

The two pages are requested by the browser with two separate HTTP GET requests: the first one for redaktionsplan.aspx, then when that page is rendered in the browser, another request is made for test.aspx.

So the code-behind on these two pages runs sequentially (not at the same time) and in the context of two different requests.

If you need to exchange data between two pages, then you can for example:

- let the first page store the data in the session, so that during the second request you can access it
- implement the functionality on the client side, using javascript

Comment: Thanks for your hints. With Javascript I can access the Controls in the iFrame (text.aspx) from the Parentpage (redaktionsplan.aspx)?- Concret: I have a GridControl in redaktionsplan.aspx and when the user select a record, I need to load data into controls (and set it enabled/disabled), which are in test.aspx on the iframe. Perhaps you can give me a sample how to do this?